# Use of c_str() for wstrings in c++

Tags: c++, widestring, c-str

When I have a:

```
std::string s
```

I can do:

```
s.c_str()
```

to convert it to a `char*`. As I understand it only adds a '\0' to the end of s.

Can I then conclude that just adding '\0' converts a string to a `char*`?
Is doing something like that converting it to `char*` then?

```
std::string s = "Hi ";
s[2] = '\0'
```

Does `.c_str()` convert all strings to their corresponding character pointer? E.g.  for `std::string`, `std::u8string`, `std::wstring`, `std::u16string`, `std::u32string`, does `c_str()` convert them to `char*`, `char8_t*`, `wchar_t*`, `char16_t*`, `char32_t*` respectively?

Comment: One question per Stackoverflow question, please. Can you [edit] and leave only one question to be answered, here?

Comment: No, and no. First no: `c_str()` does not modify the internal string. It can't, because the function is const. The string therefore must already be stored with the terminator in place. Second no: `c_str()` returns a pointer to the underlying character type. No conversion between character encodings or sizes is performed.

Comment: Hmm, just unwinding my statement here. I don't think the standard explicitly states that the string should be stored NUL-terminated. But for all practical purposes, it kinda needs to be. At the very least, it would need to allocate sufficient storage to add a string terminator in O(1) time if the `data()` or `c_str()` functions are called, and it makes no practical sense do this on-demand. It would only result in degraded performance. So, although the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) suggest the terminator need not be inline, it probably is.

Comment: @paddy [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string): *The elements of a `basic_string` are stored contiguously, that is, for a `basic_string s`, ... a pointer to `s[0]` can be passed to functions that expect a pointer to the first element of a null-terminated `CharT[]` array.*

Comment: C++ [standard draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.string.general#3): *In all cases, `[data(), data() + size()]` is a valid range, `data() + size()` points at an object with value `charT()` (a “null terminator”).*.

Comment: @Evg that might make a better answer than a comment.

Comment: An easier way to think about it. `std::string` is a class that contains a `char*` string for a member variable that is always null terminated. When you invoke `c_str()` or `data()`, it simply returns that member.